# Why is it a compile error to assign the address of an array to a pointer "my_pointer = &my_array"?

Tags: c++, arrays

```
int my_array[5] = {0};
int *my_pointer = 0;

my_pointer = &my_array;  // compiler error
my_pointer = my_array;   // ok
```

If `my_array` is address of array then what does `&my_array` gives me?

I get the following compiler error:

> error: cannot convert 'int (*)[5]' to 'int*' in assignment

Comment: The meaning of `&array` is also discussed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810664/).

Comment: @FredOverflow: Not where I can find it! Give us a pointer please (not an array, of course).

Comment: @Tony: The ASCII art below "Arrays are not pointers" explains it.

Comment: @FredOverflow: Thanks, I found it now.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

`my_array` is the name of an array of 5 integers. The compiler will happily convert it to a pointer to a single integer.

`&my_array` is a pointer to an array of 5 integers. The compiler will not treat an array of integers as a single integer, thus it refuses to make the conversion.

Comment: +1 for the distinction about treating an array of integers as a single integer.

Comment: Why do you say "is a reference to an array" instead of "is an array"?

Comment: @FredOverflow, you're right it's not technically a reference. I've edited the answer to reflect that. I still find it helpful to *think* of it as a reference though.

Comment: The most amazing answer ever!

Answer (score -1):

`&my_array` is the address at which the value of `my_array` is stored, i.e., it is the address of the address of the array and has type `int**`.

Comment: It might also be useful to know that `my_array` and `&myArray[0]` are the same thing. I've seen the latter used in code, probably just for clarity.

Comment: No, `&my_array` does **not** have type `int**`.

Comment: @slavik: No they aren't. The former is an array, the latter is a pointer.

Comment: The type of `&my_array` is actually `int(*)[5]`, not `int**`.

Comment: Is `int(*)[5]` actually an array of 5 pointers to 5 integers? How can a pointer point to 5 integers?

Comment: @user74564 `int(*)[5]` is not an array, it is the type of a pointer to an array of 5 integers. An array of 5 pointers to arrays of 5 integers would be `int (*my_array[5])[5]`

Comment: @GMan: And often when arrays are passed into a function (with a second argument giving their size), they are often passed as a pointer to the first member of the array. The name of an array serves as a pointer to the first element in the array.

Comment: @slavik: No. An array is an array, a pointer is a pointer. The name of an array is an array. An array can be converted into a pointer to the first element implicitly.

Answer (score -1):

This would be a fascinating topic for research on neuroscience, semantics, and software development. Even though we can explain the difference between my_array and &my_array, and even though we can repeat the mantra that "arrays are (or are not) pointers", this distinction is still confusing.

Usually when we take the address of something with the "&" operation, we arrive at a completely different value.

```
int x;
x=5;
cout <<x << " "<<&x<<endl;
```

First of all, let's challenge this intuition. A pointer can be accidentally equal to the value it is pointing at:

```
int* x;
x=(int*)(&x);
cout <<"same: "<<x << " "<<&x<<endl;
```

So in some contexts semantically different things can evaluate to the same thing. But just because two expressions are equal in the current context does not mean that they are interchangeable.

```
int w=3;
int* ip=&w;
void* vp=&w;
cout <<"Equal: "<<ip<<" "<<vp<<" "<<(ip==vp)<<endl;
cout <<"But not interchangeable: "<<ip+1<<" "<<vp+1<<" "<<(ip+1==vp+1)<<endl;
```

The same happens with pointers to arrays. A pointer to an array is often technically "equal" to an array itself, but since they have different semantics, there are situations in which they are not interchangeable. Try this one:

```
int my_array[5] = {5,6,7,8,9};
cout <<my_array[0]<<endl;    // output 5
cout <<(&my_array)[0]<<endl; // outputs the address of the first element
cout <<sizeof my_array[0]<<endl; // outputs 4
cout <<sizeof (&my_array)[0]<<endl; // outputs 20
```