# why g++ gives error : cannot convert ‘int (*)[3]’ to ‘int (*)[]’ in initialization

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

When I try to compile the following code with g++:

```
int main()
{
    int a[3] = {0, 1, 2};
    int (* p)[] = &a;
}
```

compiler gives the following error : "cannot convert ‘int (*)[3]’ to ‘int (*)[]’ in initialization". 
Why isn't it possible to convert int (*)[3] to int (*)[]? 
And if it is not possible then how a variable of type 'int (*)[]' should be initialized?

Comment: I compiled this code in gcc-4. It's weird. But it's legal. Try int (* p)[] = {&a};

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because you have to specify the length of the array your pointer pints to.
It should be like this:

`int (* p)[3] = &a;`

`int (*p)[]` this means that your `p` is a pointer to an array. The problem is the compiler has to know at compile time how long is the array that pointers points to, so you have to specify a value in the brackets -> `int (*p)[x]` where `x` **is known at compile time.**

Comment: Then there is no way to initialize int (* p)[]

Comment: No, there is no way to initialize it, because such a type is meaningless in C++.

Comment: @CarlNorum the type `int (*)[]` isn't meaningless. It's a pointer to an array of unknown size. dereferencing it produces an lvalue of type array of unknown size. It's even possible to access the array's elements, because the individual element size is known even if the size of the whole array isn't.

Comment: You're right - I didn't think you could even create such a variable, but a quick test here proved me wrong.

Answer (score 4):

There are many ways to initialize a variable of type `int (*)[]`. For example, it can be initialized by other values of `int (*)[]` type (including ones produced by an explicit cast) or by null-pointer constant. An `int (*)[3]` value will not immediately work since it has a different type.

In your case I'd expect this to be perfectly legal and defined

```
 int (*p)[] = (int (*)[]) &a;
```

with further access to the afray as `(*p)[i]`.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably do what you want (like access each element with `p[0]`, `p[1]`, and `p[2]`) with this:

```
int *p = a;
```

Unless you really want a pointer to a pointer, in which case use:

```
int **p = &a;
```

Comment: This is just a pointer to the first element, not the entire array.

Comment: @HunterMcMillen:  A pointer to the first element *is* a pointer to the array.

Comment: @wallyk: I don't think so -- see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5956493/address-of-an-array/17413762#17413762

Comment: C++ guarantees that array allocations are contiguous, so yes a pointer to the head is a pointer to the array.

Comment: The second declaration is completely incorrect. You cannot do `int **p = &a`. `&a` has type `int (*)[3]`, not `int **`. Forcing such value into a `int **` variable makes no sense.

Comment: please have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810664/how-do-i-use-arrays-in-c

Comment: Using a pointer instead of a pointer to an array is the typical thing to do. Arrays and pointers are not the same, however, so a pointer to a pointer and a pointer to an array are completely different, incompatible objects.

Comment: I sit corrected.  Great reference, Hunter. Basically they will always have the same value, and you can access all the elements, but they are different types according to C++'s type system.